# When configuring TFS 2010, I receive an error: "KB2580221 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer"

Tags: tfs

I am trying to install TFS Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Standard Edition). When I Start Configuring TFS on The Advanced Tab it gives a Warning and says that it requires a cumulative update for TFS - called [KB2580221](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26211).

When I downloaded and tried to run the update, it gives:

> KB2580221 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a great Q&A site, but for programming-related questions. Your question suits better at http://superuser.com/. See [faq].

Comment: I disagree. Stack Overflow is the prefect place to ask this question. The faq says "software tools commonly used by programmers", of which TFS is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

KB2580221 is "Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1 Cumulative Update 1". Service Pack 1 is a pre-requisite for it, that is why you are receiving the error message.

"Cumulative Update 2" has since been released, and since it is *cumulative*, you don't need to install Cumulative Update 1 first. (But just to make it confusing, you DO need to install Service Pack 1 first).

So, what you need to do is:

1. Run the installer for TFS 2010 RTM (you've done this), but don't run the 'configure' wizard
2. Download and install: [Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20506) (477 MB)
3. Download and install: [Team Foundation Server 2010 SP1 Cumulative Update 2](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236945&clcid=0x409) (23 MB)
4. Open the 'Team Foundation Server Administration Console' and select 'Configure installed features'

You will then have a new server running the latest version of TFS 2010.

Take a look at this blog post for a comprehensive list of patches and more information: [TFS 2010: What Service Packs and Hotfixes should I install?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2012/01/03/tfs-2010-what-service-packs-and-hotfixes-should-i-install.aspx)